stacked area chart with no y variable ggplot2
I need to create a stacked area chart with the following dataset (example):
ds <- data.frame(
  Time = c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 4)),
  Type = c("a", "c", "f", "f", "e", "q", "a", "c")
)

I know the formula should be:
ggplot(ds, aes(x=time, y=???, fill=Type)) +
  geom_area()

My question is what do I put in the y value to have the count or the proportion of Type elements for each given Time?

Please do not post images of data for these reasons. Instead, add code that creates your ds object in a codeblock. Also, update your question to include an example of the output that you want. It can be a sketch if you are unable to produce an example plot.

You can count the occurrences of different Types at each Time point, then map that variable to the y-axis.
Data set
set.seed(123)
ds <- data.frame(
  Time = rep(1:10, each = 50),
  Type = sample(LETTERS[1:6], 500, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.1,0.15,0.2,
                                                       0.1,0.25,0.2))
)

Count and plot
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ds |>
  count(Time, Type) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = n, fill = Type)) +
  geom_area()


Created on 2024-04-05 with reprex v2.0.2
